# Unable to install Android / ARC app from Chrome Web Store on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have an Android app which I "made into" a Chrome OS app by using ARC Welder, and published in Chrome Web Store (per documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aquamail/immkckhpjjkikagmhfnpjjcnaelegjel

( the app is called AquaMail )

Now, I don't own any Chrome OS devices, so Chrome Web Store just says "wrong OS" for me, but...

Someone with a Chrome OS device was unable to install the app with this message:

> Unable to install "AquaMail" because it is not allowed by "App Runtime for Chrome (Beta)"

How can I find out what's wrong?

As first step, I guess I'd like to get a more detailed error message, how can the user do that? Is there anything equivalent to logcat?

Or maybe someone from Google / ARC team can try installing as a sanity check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to install "AquaMail" because it is not allowed by "App Runtime for Chrome (Beta)"

This is an error message indicating the user has an older version of ARC than the current one available. There used to be a whitelist that controlled what apps could be uploaded and installed but it has since been removed. This error message is a whitelist restriction being enforced.

Have the user check what version of ARC they have in chrome://extensions with developer mode enabled, and compare to the version that is currently shipping via https://arc-omahaproxy.appspot.com

If it is not current, they can try clicking "Update extensions", or more drastically they could uninstall all ARC apps and reinstall.

Comment: "Have the user check what version of ARC they have in chrome://extensions with developer mode enabled" -- where does one get ARC for Chrome OS? I have a brand-new Acer Chromebook 11, and there are no extensions installed (when viewed as Guest), let alone an ARC one.

Comment: To answer my own inquiry, [the ARC Welder app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn), despite being described as an app, actually (also?) installs an extension. This cannot be installed in Guest mode.

Comment: Yes, ARC Welder, similar to ARC Apps, requires the ARC extension to function.  If you do not have ARC installed when the first ARC App or ARC Welder is installed, it will download and install automatically.